# Logging all Events in Laravel 5.1 without hitting "nesting" exception

Tags: laravel, events, laravel-5.1

How can I log all Events in Laravel 5.1? I tried but get this error:

**Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached**

I have tried setting the **xdebug** nesting level to a higher value (900) with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the following in your **EventServiceProvider's** `boot` function. The key is to filter out "**illuminate.log**" events. If you don't filter those out, your logging statement will result in recursive evaluation of your Event handler.

Note that the Laravel framework seems to make extensive use of events for it's own purposes, so you will see lots of "internal" framework events listed in your log as well.

```
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);

    Event::listen('*', function()
    {
        $event = Event::firing();
        if(!starts_with($event, "illuminate.log")) {
            Log::info("Event fired: " . $event . "\n");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Bryan's answer, here's a snippet that works for Laravel 10.16.x:

```php
Event::listen('*', static function (string $event): void {
    if (Str::startsWith($event, MessageLogged::class)) {
        return;
    }

    logger(sprintf('Event fired: %s', $event));
});
```

Paste it in your application or any other service provider's `boot` method.